# Explain transitive dependencies strategy described in Android Build System documentation

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Can someone explain what the Android tools team means in this short paragraph quoted below?

Specifically:
What is "somelib.jar"?

Are they suggesting, that I create a new sub project that has only dependencies, call it "projectA" then have the project publish "projectA.jar"? (using artifacts.add("default", file('projectA.jar'))

The intended behavior that I want is to publish "projectA.jar" along with its dependencies without causing any "multiple dex files define" errors.

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Handling-transitive-dependencies-for-local-artifacts-jars-and-aar-

Quote:

> If you have a local jar or aar library that you want to use in more
>   than one project, you cannot just reference it directly as a local
>   dependency. This is because the android plugin will complain if it
>   finds the same jar file twice when dexing the project and all its
>   dependencies. (Note that right now you can't actually use a local aar
>   file even if you only reference it once).
>
> One way to fix this is to deploy the artifact in a repository. While
>   it's possible, it might not be convenient due to the overhead of
>   managing such a repository.
>
> Another option is to create a new Gradle sub-project, and to make this
>   project's published artifact be the jar or aar file that you want to
>   reuse. Then you can simply have other Gradle sub-projects depend on
>   this new sub-project.
>
> In this new sub-project, simply create a build.gradle with the
>   following:
>
> configurations.create("default")
>
> artifacts.add("default", file('somelib.jar'))

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is mainly used for library module.

If one library module depends on `somelib.jar`, another application module which depends on the library module also depends on `somelib.jar`, then "multiple dex files define" errors might come.

As the "Tips" say, the problem can be solved by create a simple module, which is unable to publish `*.jar` or `*.aar` and **only used to be depended on by other modules**, with just the dependency `*.jar`s. With this, the library module's `*.aar` output will not include the `somelib.jar`.